# 403 Error when indexing data from AWS Lambda to Elasticsearch using Sig v4: 'no permissions for [indices:data/write/bulk] '

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, boto3

My function can index documents in single and bulk to my AWS Elasticsearch from a local Jupyter notebook, but when I deploy to Lambda it keeps returning this error:

```
"errorMessage": "AuthorizationException(403, 'security_exception', 'no permissions for
[indices:data/write/bulk] and User [name=arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/MyLambdaRole,
backend_roles=[arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/MyLambdaRole], requestedTenant=null]')"
```

My Elasticsearch domain (v7.7) is configured as such:

```
Fine-grained access control: Enabled
Master user type: Internal user database
SAML authentication: Disabled
Amazon Cognito for authentication: Disabled
Require HTTPS: Enabled
Encryption at rest: Enabled
KMS master keyarn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:key/<aws/es key>
Node-to-node encryption: Enabled
```

The domain's access policy contains:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The IAM policy for MyLambdaRole contains:

```
...
        {
            "Action": [
                "es:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
```

In Kibana I have mapped both my AWS admin IAM user and MyLambdaRole under Security -> Role Mappings -> all_access. I have tried different combinations of adding them to Backend roles and also adding them to security_manager.

The Lambda uses AWS Signature v4 authentication and the elasticsearch client is version 7.7.0:

```py
import boto3
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection, helpers
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()

awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, \
    session.region_name, 'es', session_token=credentials.token)

host = 'search-es-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = awsauth
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)

# Single indexing call
document = { my data }
es.index(index="my_index", doc_type="_doc", id=doc_id, body=document)

# Bulk indexing call
k = ({ my data })
helpers.bulk(es, k)
```

If I replace `http_auth = awsauth` with my Kibana credentials `http_auth = (kibana_username, kibana_password)` it returns status 200 but then no new documents are created in the index which is weird.

I would like to know what I could be missing or where my configuration could be off.

Answer (score 10):

This is because of fine grained access control being enabled. I ran into the exact same problem and fine grained access control causes issues. Your notebook might be using the master ARN you specified which has access and is always allowed basically.

I recreated my ES instance and disabled fine grained access control and used domain policy only as it suited our set up.

Read more here and notice the highlighted section re user / IAM mixing and not working correctly.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using Opensearch. I was facing the same issue when inserting the document. This blog help me. They suggested add a lambda role ARN in  that accesses Open search dashboards/Kibana in Roles -> Mapp users -> Manage mapping -> Backend Roles. For me it worked. Detail steps are mentioned in below url

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/opensearch-troubleshoot-cloudwatch-logs/ [enter link description here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/opensearch-troubleshoot-cloudwatch-logs/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`"type":"security_exception","reason":"no permissions for [indices:data/write/bulk]`
For anybody facing this and other similar security errors with **OpenSearch**, in my case they were caused by the AWS OpenSearch domain being configured with [Fine-grained access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html) as already mentioned. With such configuration, you need to give the proper permissions to the IAM role being used by fluent-bit in the OpenSearch admin console:

[image]